# Accessing an API from webserver in xamarin android application

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Having an issue parsing results from API into my textview objects... please, I need help:

```
{"items":[{"id":0,"shortname":"NETD","_links":{"self":{"href":"http://api.iolab.net/v1/exams/0"}}}]
```

and this is my code:

```
Protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

    // Get our button from the layout resource,
    // and attach an event to it
    //EditText latitude = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1);
    EditText latitude = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1);
    Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
    button.Click += async (sender, e) =>
    {
        string url = "http://api.iolab.net/v1/exams?";

        // Fetch the information asynchronously, parse the results,
        // then update the screen:
        JsonValue json = await FetchExamAsync(url);
        ParseAndDisplay(json);
    };

}

private async Task<JsonValue> FetchExamAsync(string url)
{
    // Create an HTTP web request using the URL:
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Method = "GET";

    // Send the request to the server and wait for the response:
    using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
    {
        // Get a stream representation of the HTTP web response:
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            // Use this stream to build a JSON document object:
            JsonValue jsonDoc = await Task.Run(() => JsonObject.Load(stream));
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Response: {0}", jsonDoc.ToString());

            // Return the JSON document:
            return jsonDoc;
        }

    } 
}

private void ParseAndDisplay(JsonValue json)
{

    TextView id = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
    TextView Shortname = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView2);
    TextView links = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView3);

    // Extract the array of name/value results for the field name "item":
    // Note that there is no exception handling for when this field is not found.
    JsonValue Results = json["items"];
    id.Text = Results["id"];

    Shortname.Text = Results["shortname"];
    links.Text = Results["_links"];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to parse json in .NET application ( including Xamarin ) is to use [Newtonsoft](http://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema) nuget package and http://json2csharp.com/ website

Moreever you are not following the Xamarin Architecture, please put your asynchrone call in the portable library because this cose can be used in all platforms.

Here the example with newtosoft :

```
//generated with json2csharp
//each class correspond to the json string retrieve by the back end

//{"href":"http://api.iolab.net/v1/exams/0"}
public class Self
{
    public string href { get; set; }
}

//"_links":{"self":{"href":"http://api.iolab.net/v1/exams/0"}
public class Links
{
    public Self self { get; set; }
}

//{"items":[{"id":0,"shortname":"NETD","_links":{"self":{"href":"http://api.iolab.net/v1/exams/0"}}}]}
public class Item
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string shortname { get; set; }
    public Links _links { get; set; }
}

//Rott object
public class RootObject
{
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
}
```

to parse your json to an item :

```
//json is the json string retrieve from the backend
//this method will convert the json to an item object if is possible
var item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item>(json);
```

to parse a list of item :

```
//json is the json string retrieve from the backend
//this method will convert the json to a list of item object if is possible
var listitem =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(json);
```

I give you also my generic method to call GET method from a web service :

```
 //param is a get parameter and i actually optional
 public static async Task<String> RunGetAsync(string param = "")
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;
            string url = "http://api.iolab.net/v1;
            string path = "/exam";
            //try catch can be deleted, i use it for timeout, task issues or web issues.
            try
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {   
                    //create a client based in webservice url 
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);

                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    //timeout to call the backend
                    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
                    //if request is not allowAnonymous

                    //adding request header
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                    //to create a specific path for the call
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(param))
                    {
                        response = await client.GetAsync(path);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        response = await client.GetAsync(Path + "/" + param);
                    }

                    //check if the call succeed
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        //get the response into string content & return it
                        var stringContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        return stringContent;

                    }

                    return null;
                }
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
                return null;
            }
            catch (WebException we)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(we.Message);
                return null;
            }

}
```

If you have any questions, don't hesitate to comment this post

Comment: thank you.... i am still learning c# in general.. don't understand some things in the code.. pls help..

Comment: OK, i will comment & simplyfy as much as possible the code i puted before

Comment: I change as much as possible the explanation & the code, remember that the method RunGetAsync is generic and should be put in your portable library. Morever, if you are new at C# developing, this kind of things can be hard to assimilate, don't hesitate to back learning basis ( async call, web calls etc... ). hope this few changes help you

Comment: one last thing please.. have textviews already.. how do i parse the results to those textviews??

Comment: instead of that  id.Text = Results["id"]; use this id.Text = item.id ( related to this code : var item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item>(json); )

Comment: thank you OrcusZ....will post my code.. dont know how to call it in my button click method....

Comment: link everything with a button1_click event... i know im going to add the ParseAndDisplay(json) to the button1_click event.. but what else??

Comment: for example:  
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           JsonValue json = await RunGetAsync();
            ParseAndDisplay(json);
        }
        public async Task<String> RunGetAsync(string param = "")
        {

}
its returning error...